# pass parameter to context menu's selector method

Tags: objective-c, methods, parameters, selector

how can i pass a parameter to the following selector?

```
   NSMenuItem *item3 = [[NSMenuItem alloc] initWithTitle:title3 action:@selector(uncheckrow:)  keyEquivalent:@""];
```

i would like to pass on the number of the row to the method.

Thanks

EDIT

the row i want to pass is the row of the table i rightclicked in the first place. but it could be any integer variable..

Comment: which row you want to pass and whats the context that this menu item is set i.e is it for mainmenu or context menu ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Override the menuForEvent: in your tableview's subclass, Take some variable in your controller say 'rowToApply'

```
- (NSMenu*) menuForEvent:(NSEvent*)event
{
    NSPoint point = [self convertPoint:[event locationInWindow] fromView:nil];
    NSInteger row = [self rowAtPoint:point];
    BOOL clickWasOnItem = (row > -1);
        if(clickWasOnItem) {
            controller.rowToApply = [self itemAtRow:row];// Controller can be datasource(or) delegate (or) someObject which can be accessible)
        }
    return [super menuForEvent:event];
}
```

you can use the rowToApply: in contextualMenu item's action method (uncheckrow:).

Answer (score 1):

The menu item itself (`item3` your snippet) will be sent to the method, so you can identify the particular selected menu item that way.  You can also set the NSMenuItem's tag property, for example: `[item3 setTag:3]` and then in your uncheckrow method you can use `NSInteger row = [sender tag];`

**Edit: For updated question**

If you want to send an arbitrary integer to this method then there are options, but they aren't particularly elegant.  AppKit will always send the NSMenuItem as the sender, so you need to make the integer available to the NSMenuItem being unchecked.  Note that NSMenuItems have access to their parent NSMenus, through the `menu` method.  So if the parent NSMenu itself has some property you can take advantage of, you can use `[[sender menu] thatProperty]`.  Since you're showing the NSMenu in response to a right click on a table's row, you could set the property before you show the menu.  I recommend subclassing NSMenu to add your own "spawningRowIndex" property (choose a better name though).  Before showing the NSMenu set the property and when you receive uncheckrow you can use `[[sender menu] spawningRowIndex]`.

Comment: thanks! the row i want to send is not the row of the selected menu, but the row the user has right clicked in the first place to display the menu. sorry if i didnt specify this.

Comment: @Justme OK I have updated my answer to try to help with the edited question.  I'm afraid I don't know an *elegant* way to get the index of the right-clicked table row to that method, but I can suggest some less elegant ways to do it.

Comment: thanks, but the other answer is more elegant.. but thank you anyway! upvoted your answer!